# eBook 400 страниц react/react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Как бы вы реализовали обработку большого объема текста в react-native/react app? У меня есть eBook книга в (.doc/.txt) ~400 страниц текста. Хочу сделать 2 кнопки "Назад" и "Вперед" чтобы переключаться между страницами текста книги.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как бы вы обрабатывали такой большой объём информации, чтобы разбить его на много кусков и подгружать их при нажатии?

Любые идеи и предложения приветствуются!

Comment: Если это просто текст, то не такие уж и большие. Я бы засунул в json. протестил на целевом устройстве / скорости сети. А уж потом оптимизировал.

Comment: А pagination как?

У меня из идей только: пропарсить файл, разбить весь текст на куски по 400 символов и засунуть их в array где index - номер страницы книги, value - кусок текста (string) = O(1) lookup при пагинации.

Может есть идеи получше?)

Comment: Мозжет сразу на страницы и разбить, или они от размера экрана зависят?